# an array's dimension must be an integer between 1 and 1000

Tags: crystal-reports

Does anyone has any clue about the above error i get when I've tried to create sub report in crystal report?

```
Shared Stringvar array store;
store:= store + {table.A};
1
```

Comment: still you are trying this way? didn't you try writing query?

Comment: Error means, your array is full and it can't store any more values,

Comment: @siva Actually I've followed your advice but still didnt work. See the screenshot

Comment: @siva And the i wrote the below code in sql to merge the 2 columns:   Select concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) as EventName,CROSS_REF
from tizone1.baseevent -- See the Screenshot

Comment: Then i've used the left outer join to compare the values of the two columns and remove all the duplicate rows

Comment: @siva  Code:                                                                                               
 Select concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) as EventName,CROSS_REF
from tizone1.baseevent 
where concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) in

(
SELECT  baseevent.CROSS_REF 
from tizone1.baseevent as ta
left  join tizone1.baseevent as lta
on ta.EventName = lta.CROSS_REF
group by master_key
);

Comment: what is the resultset of the above query ?

Comment: @Siva  I still getting all the values of 2 columns without removing the duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Try below, you are again selecting the values that are their in both tables but you need to select that are not in second table, I have updated the query

```
Select concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) as EventName,CROSS_REF from tizone1.baseevent where concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) not in ( SELECT baseevent.CROSS_REF from tizone1.baseevent as ta left join tizone1.baseevent as lta on ta.EventName = lta.CROSS_REF group by master_key );
```

Comment: I getting this error:   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ta.EventName' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Rumi this you need to check the name of column in database, column name used is wrong

Comment: When i run the query in sql without subquery is working. I think is to do with the EventName

Comment: <pre> Select master_key,concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) as EventName,CROSS_REF
from tizone1.baseevent 
where concat(REFNO_PFIX,'00',REFNO_SERL) not in 

(
SELECT baseevent.CROSS_REF
from tizone1.baseevent as ta
left outer join tizone1.baseevent as lta
on ta.REFNO_PFIX = lta.CROSS_REF
where ta.REFNO_PFIX is  null  

);  <code>

Comment: When i add the above query is working.But not sure if is the right one.I can't add code into comment!!

Comment: what is the result set of the query? is the result set correct?

Comment: I'm gonna just check it out in crystal report

Comment: @Rumi ccrystal doesn't give correct data if database returns wrong data so to get correct data you need to set the query first

Comment: so event name is not a database field, correct? do you have experience in SQL queries?

Comment: Yes, correct is just a random name could be anything. I have had some experience, but now I'm trying to recap

Comment: without knowing your database structure it is not possible to suggest on the queries

Comment: You right, the database i am working on is a hierarchical database model and is quite sophisticated to retrive data. But finally I've managed to solve the problem in sql and now it works in crystal report.

Comment: @Rumi great.. happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.. Just out of curiosity, I am still trying to understand why it didn't work in crystal report at the first place. But I raised this issue with SAP and the recommended the below advise.

Comment: To add a value to an array, you have to do this (Crystal syntax):   *******                                              Shared Stringvar array store;
Numbervar size = length(store);
if size = 1 and store[1] = "" then 
  store[1] := {table.A}
else (
  size := size + 1;
  Redim Preserve store [size];
  store[size] := {table.A}
);***

Comment: Does that ring a bell for you?!

Comment: @Rumi this is static way of array creation, can I ask you are you getting the same error with this formula?

Comment: Yes i get the same error but what i did in sql i've created a view table and import the main columns and know even your logic is works

Comment: @Rumi yes you will get the same error because it is CR constraint, you need to tweak the logic a bit more with the same formula. anyway issue resolved congrats

Comment: Do you think is way to tweak this formula? If you check the above  screenshot. I try to change the formula in sub query but still does'nt work.

Comment: @Rumi we can tweak but it is difficult to explain in SO forum need some close monitoring and testing but yes this can be done

Comment: Hi Siva Can you help me out with this new challenge! Basically, I am trying to show the highest values in column B which is related to uniqe reference.I've tried the above formula but that didn't work.

Comment: I screenshot the  expected out put

Comment: @Rumi create a new question will try to answer their

Comment: I've created a new question if you could take a look thanks